# How do I say what is the current UTC in eastern zone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

No matter what server is being used, I want a way to be able to just get the Eastern UTC time. All my timestamps in the system is setup for est, but my Azure server is set to UTC, but my local dev box and staging site is on est. What is the best way? Thanks for any help.

```
var estZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now, estZone);
```

Comment: Like `DateTime.UtcNow`?

Comment: What if the server is already on Utc Time?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. If Server time is a UTC time of 3:01 am and I call UTC.now on that server, wont it get the UTC time of 3:01am which is like 8:01 am?

Comment: Try `DateTime.UtcNow` as suggested above. How hard could that be?

Comment: Eastern UTC time does not exist. It either UTC, either Eastern. So which one do you need?

Answer (score 3):

UTC is UTC.  It is the same everywhere.